# popover is showing at top left corner as the width of the div is very small like < 2.5 px

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

I was using reactstrap popover in my react js code . Popover is showing at topleft corner as the width of the div is almost less than 2.5px

I was using versions mentioned below
 "reactstrap": "^7.0.1",
"react": "^16.3.2",

```
<Popover placement="bottom" style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',  textAlign: 'left', width: '235px' }} isOpen={this.props.popoverVisible} target={this.props.target}>
                    <PopoverBody>
                        <div>
                            {this.getPopOverName(this.props.item)}
                            <div><b>Start: </b>{this.dateObject.start}</div>
                            <div><b>End: </b>{this.dateObject.end}</div>
                        </div>
                    </PopoverBody>
                </Popover>
```

![enter image description here[1]][1]

Comment: what is your expected behavior?

Comment: Thank you for responding @AkberIqbal I was expecting to display the popover below the div when hovered over it .currently it is displaying on top left of the screen

Comment: the popover will display relative to the div... in your case since the div containing the popover is tiny and on the left, the popover is displaying relative to it... if you move the div away from the left, the popover can be displayed much in the middle; check https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7qpgyj

Comment: @AkberIqbal i was expecting the same behaviour.sorry to mention there is litte change to css in div tag . I just added css to it .This is was my actual issue

You can check the one here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6jacyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6jacyr) in the comments, remove the `border-style:solid;` property from your styles.css to get the same result as I had [suggested here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7qpgyj)

relevant **CSS**:

```
.tinyDiv{
  background:red; height:10px; width:3px; margin-left:10%;
  /* border-style:solid; */
  border-width:2px;
  border-color:blue;
}
```

relevant **JS**:

```
class MyPopOver extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      popoverOpen: false
    };
  }

  onHover = () => {
  this.setState({
    popoverOpen: true,
  })
}

onHoverLeave = () => {
  this.setState({
    popoverOpen: false,
  })
}

  render() {
    return (<>
      <div className='tinyDiv' id="Popover1" onMouseEnter={this.onHover}
   onMouseLeave={this.onHoverLeave}>
        <Popover placement="bottom" isOpen={this.state.popoverOpen} target="Popover1" style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'}}>
          <PopoverBody>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</PopoverBody>
        </Popover>
      </div></>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution , It worked for me but i need the border, instead of border i used the outline and the issue is fixed finally.